# Solving invalid geometries

Tags: qgis, shapefile, terrascan

I have ASCII data from different parts of water bottoms.
I would like to convert all the parts into shapefiles.

But, when I use the polygonize raster to vector tool in QGIS I get invalid geometries. To solve this I tried using the validation tool and also the v.buffer function in GRASS. After using that it keeps giving new invalid objects.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then please [edit] your question to include details about any steps you have tried and any error messages you've received.

Comment: The shapefile specification allows for null shapes, but even if *all* the shapes were null, you couldn't exceed 179m features, and if they're all valid points, you couldn't exceed 77m features (these numbers assume no more than 12 bytes of attributes per null feature and no more than 38 bytes per point)

Comment: Thanks Vince, do you mean 179m2? And how did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: He meant millions of features. The maximum shapefile component file size is 2GB, which usually translates to somewhere around a hundred million points.

Comment: Oh of course haha.. size should not be the problem then

Comment: As a side note, if you want a user to get a notification for a comment, add a @ sign like this : @Vince